# What branch/field of mathematics is this?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I do not want solutions, I just want the field/branch of mathematics that these problems deal with, and possibly a good online source or two to learn it.

Problems :-

### 1:-

[image]

### 2:-

[image]

### 3:-

[image]

### 4:-

### [image]

Sorry about that, the problems I was referring to are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ptnh.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your question.  You haven't specified which problems you are talking about.  Please update your post and then we can help. :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments: the problems are the type that would typically show up in the introductory parts of real analysis.